# Azure Service Fabric Reverse Proxy access to content files

Tags: azure, dns, reverse-proxy, relative-path, azure-service-fabric

I've published a few Microservices to ASF Cluster and exposed all HTTP endpoints using reverse proxy. I've got web application that setup as microservice and I'm trying to access homepage using next url
`http://app.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19008/APPLICATION/SERVICE1/Home/Index` but I'm getting 404 errors for all css/js resources. For example It looks for `site.css` in `http://app.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19008/content/site.css` instead of `http://app.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19008/APPLICATION/SERVICE1/site.css`.

How can I solve that problem without changing css/js links ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the css/js links. Set up a variable in your razor templates that has your application/service path and prefix all your links with it.